# Stop all instances in google cloud platform

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to write a script in python 3.8 in cloud functions to stop all of the instances (VM's) no matter about the region, instance name etc. Moreover I'm looking for Tag specified too. However I didn't found an answer anywhere, everywhere it's said I need to give project id, region and instance name. Is there any option to jump over it?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [aggregatedList()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/compute_v1.instances.html#aggregatedList) and [aggregatedList_next()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/compute_v1.instances.html#aggregatedList_next) methods to list all instances in all zones. Use the [stop()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/compute_v1.instances.html#stop) method to terminate an instance. To understand the data returned by aggregatedList(), study the REST API [response body](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/aggregatedList).

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
service = discovery.build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# Project ID for this request.
project = "REPLACE_ME"

request = service.instances().aggregatedList(project=project)
while request is not None:
    response = request.execute()
    instances = response.get('items', {})
    for instance in instances.values():
      for i in instance.get('instances', []):
          # Do something here to determine if this instance should be stopped.

          # Stop instance
          response = service.instances().stop(project=project, zone=zone, instance=i)

          # Add code to check the response, see below
    request = service.instances().aggregatedList_next(previous_request=request, previous_response=response)
```

Example code to check the `response` status returned by `stop()`. You might want to stop all instances and save each response in a list and then process the list until all instances have stopped.

```
while True:
    result = service.zoneOperations().get(
                project=project,
                zone=zone,
                operation=response['name']).execute()

    print('status:', result['status'])

    if result['status'] == 'DONE':
        print("done.")
        break;

    if 'error' in result:
        raise Exception(result['error'])

    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Okay so I added it to the function with entry point stop_vm, and without auth since I don't really need it for that, however I'm getting error that it couldn't handle the request, seems like it can't find the instance? just my guess, I'm adding the code in the next comment or edit.

Comment: @Montana - Your question has been answered. If you have additional questions or problems post a new question.

Comment: okay I did everything as you said and it keeps giving me `stop_vm operation=response['name']).execute() TypeError: 'HttpRequest' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: @Montana - On Stack Overflow ask one question per post. Get an answer. If you have another question or another problem, post a new question. In your next question include the details for your new question or new problem.